# How do I JOIN a table with dates on another table with a start date and end date?

Tags: sql, database, join

I have a table that maps out what dates go into which Fiscal Period with two fields: Start Date and End Date. I have another table with shipment dates and wanted to pull in the Fiscal Period field into the shipment dates table corresponding to which shipment date falls in between the start and end dates.

- Table 1: Start Date, End Date, Fiscal Period
- Table 2: Ship Date
- Table 3: Ship Date, Fiscal Period

Answer (score 0):

```
select t2.ShipDate,
    (select FiscalPeriod from t1 where t2.ShipDate between StartDate and EndDate) as FiscalPeriod
from t2
```